# What are the main differences between the God of the Bible and God of Quran?

Tags: nature-of-god, islam, comparative-religion

The Bible reveals the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob progressively from the first book Genesis to the last book Revelations. The teachings of the Prophets and the Apostles not only concur with each other but also reinforce on the attributes, essence, and activities of God.

Muslims' holy  book Quran repeatedly refers to the Prophets of the Bible as well as the God of those Prophets. It even recounts some of the incidents and the way God dealt with people as mentioned in the Bible. Besides, the Quran makes clear claims that it has been given to confirm the precious Scriptures i.e. Torah, Psalms, Prophets, and the Gospels, [The Bible]. Yet, Christians see the Quran different from the Bible in teachings as well as in presenting the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.

What exactly are the strange things or characters that protestant Christians see in the God of Quran that are incompatible with the God of the Bible?

Comment: You would need to scope this question. Unitarians would have a very different view of the 'God of the Bible' to Trinitarians. Roman Catholics would have a different view to Protestants. And so on. You will get a different answer depending on whom you ask. There is no 'common' answer which will be applicable to all viewpoints.

Comment: Christians regard the New Testament as part of "the Bible." Therefore, the Bible indicates that:
1. Jesus is God.
2. In his human nature, Jesus literally died.
3. Jesus's death and resurrection saves us.
By contrast, the Quran teaches that:
1. Jesus is not God.
2. Jesus did not actually die, but only appeared to die.
3. We are not saved by Jesus's death and resurrection.
Since these differences are at the very core of Christianity, the Bible and Quran are incompatible in their description of God.